# Avoiding, in general, "undefined method 'some_method' for nil:NilClass" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, null, duck-typing

Ruby's duck-typing is great, but this is the one way that it bites me in the ass. I'll have some long running text-processing script or something running, and after several hours, some unexpected set of circumstances ends up causing the script to exit with at `NoMethodError` due to a variable becoming `nil`.

Now, once it happens, it's usually an easy fix, but it would be nicer if I could predict these better, or at least handle these types of errors more gracefully. Sorry for the vagueness of the question, but this type of error just happens too often to me and I wonder if there's a good way to avoid it.

Is there some best practice related to these kinds of "type errors" for Ruby?

Comment: Define Object.method_missing? Seriously, if unexpected circumstances ends up causing the script to exit with a NoMethodError, I'd say the script needs to be fixed.

Comment: You're asking how you can prevent variables from "accidentally" becoming nil? Fix your logic errors.

Comment: @Mark, obviously the script needs to be fixed, yes. I'm asking if there's some way to avoid the problem in the first place, as it happens just a bit too often that I think I may just be ignorant of some best practice related to this.

Comment: @meager, there are many ways for variables to become nil besides "logic errors". More than I expect often, which may be the root of this problem.

Comment: `NoMethodError` is the equivalent of `NullPointerException` in Java, so I am afraid, you have to take care of it while coding, which I think is the best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). It's useful in many programming paradigms, but it's particularly useful when you don't have a compiler to help you catch these sort of errors, of forbidding particular sorts of values for a parameter.

In essence, DbC allows you to make an assumption about a parameter. It allows you (in all but one place) to skip the mundane checks that guarantee this assumption to hold.

Comment: Very interesting, and addresses my question well, thanks. However, is it really worth the overhead? Seems like it would almost be just as well to switch to a strongly typed language. I see there's an (unmaintained) Ruby library though, so it's definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

What about Object.nil?

Comment: Sure, but usually if an object is nil when I expected it to be a string or something, it means there was some problem earlier on that was unanticipated. Anticipating these problems is the hard part, not dealing with nil values that you know are going to occur.